# iOS: record dynamic audio playback

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, audiounit

I'm trying to record audio output that is being dynamically generated out of local audio files.

So let's say I have one audio file "drums.mp3", and I'm currently playing it in a loop like this:

```
var drumSoundEffect: AVAudioPlayer!
var repeatTimer: NSTimer!
var url: NSURL!
let soundInterval: NSTimeInterval = 1

@IBAction func playSoundTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    initSound()
    initAndStartTimer()
}    

func initSound() {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("drums.mp3", ofType: nil)!
    url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path);
}

func initAndStartTimer() {
    repeatTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(soundInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(playSound), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    repeatTimer.fire()
}

func playSound() {
    do {
        let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
        drumSoundEffect = sound
        sound.play()
    } catch {
        //an error occurred...
    }
}
```

When I try to add the AVAudioRecorder functionality, it seems it is ONLY recording from the microphone, and not from the audio I'm generating... From what I found in the internet it seems that AVFoundation is only capable to record from mic so this is not the right choice for my scenario. 
[This](http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/) example seems to be quite promising, but I simply have no clue how to create a working sample app out of it. I know this question is quite generic, but maybe somebody could give me a hint on this anyway?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using the [AmazingAudioEngine](http://theamazingaudioengine.com). Works like a charm once digging into the sample app

Comment: Glad you did. It is an example of high-quality open-source audio API, worth learning from.